# Kubernetes included quotes in *.jar. How to exlude this quotes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I need to add Java command in container. For it I use Helm Chart.

```
helm install mychart chart/mychart --set "command.cmd={java,-Disurz_dir=/mnt/isurz,-Dnifi_url=http://srv-ft-ads-01:9090/nifi-api/processors/20e6a079-3721-a43a-0fed7a8f1236,-Des_host_and_port=xxx:9200,-jar,*.jar}"
```

The result isn't what I expected:

```
 spec:                                                                                                                                                                                     
   containers:                                                                                                                                                                             
   - command:                                                                                                                                                                              
     - java                                                                                                                                                                                
     - -Disurz_dir=/mnt/isurz                                                                                                                                                              
     - -Dnifi_url=http://srv-ft-ads-01:9090/nifi-api/processors/20e6a079-3721-a43a-0fed7a8f1236                                                                                   
     - -Des_host_and_port=xxx:9200                                                                                                                                                
     - -jar                                                                                                                                                                                
     - '*.jar'
```

I don't understand why Kubernetes puts quotes in `*.jar`.

If instead `*.jar` specify `myapp.jar` then Kubernetes don't add quotes:

```
helm install mychart chart/mychart --set "command.cmd={java,-Disurz_dir=/mnt/isurz,-Dnifi_url=http://srv-ft-ads-01:9090/nifi-api/processors/20e6a079-3721-a43a-0fed7a8f1236,-Des_host_and_port=xxx:9200,-jar,myapp.jar}"
```

Result:

```
 spec:                                                                                                                                                                                     
   containers:                                                                                                                                                                             
   - command:                                                                                                                                                                              
     - java                                                                                                                                                                                
     - -Disurz_dir=/mnt/isurz                                                                                                                                                              
     - -Dnifi_url=http://srv-ft-ads-01:9090/nifi-api/processors/20e6a079-3721-a43a-0fed7a8f1236                                                                                   
     - -Des_host_and_port=xxx:9200                                                                                                                                                
     - -jar                                                                                                                                                                                
     - myapp.jar
```

Comment: The quotes are necessary because an unquoted `*` can't start a YAML value. They are not part of the value itself.

Comment: Thanks. I checked - you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as a community wiki, feel free to edit and expand.

---

As @larsks correctly mentioned in the comment:

> The quotes are necessary because an unquoted * can't start a YAML
> value. They are not part of the value itself.

For example, this is from [YAML syntax](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html#gotchas) document:

> In addition to ' and " there are a number of characters that are
> special (or reserved) and cannot be used as the first character of an
> unquoted scalar: [] {} > | * & ! % # ` @ ,.

And in much more details with examples it's available in [YAML spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#53-indicator-characters).